# If $f<1$, $f(0)^2 + f'(0)^2=4$, exists $x_0$ s.t. $f''(x_0) + f(x_0)=0$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is $C^2$, $f < 1$ for all $x$, and $f(0)^2 + f'(0)^2=4$. Show that $\exists x_0$ s.t. $f''(x_0) + f(x_0)=0$.

So far, I have let $\phi(x) = f(x)^2 + f'(x)^2$. Then $$\phi'(x) = 2f(x)f'(x) + 2f'(x)f''(x) = 2f'(x)(f(x) + f''(x)).$$

So we need to show that there's a critical point of $\phi$ that is not a critical point of $f$. I believe this is supposed to be an exercise in the mean value theorem, but I don't know where to find another value of $\phi(x)$.

Any ideas?

(This is a problem from a teacher's set of notes, so of course there could be a typo. Could it be that $|f|<1$ is what he meant, for instance?)

Comment: It could be that he meant for $f$ to be a non-negative function such that $f<1$.  I agree that some such restriction appears to be necessary.

Comment: As stated, $f \equiv -2$ is a counterexample. So a restriction is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f\equiv -2$ is a counter-example. So there must be an additional restriction. I will post this as a wiki, in case anyone can solve it, given a reasonable restriction.